# MySQL MyISAM table locking

Tags: sql, mysql, locking, myisam

Does a MySQL MyISAM table gets locked when records are deleted from it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

MyISAM tables supports table level locking, and yes, a write lock is employed when deleting (or insert & updating) records.

For more info, see [Internal Locking Methods](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/internal-locking.html)