# How to lock tables with codeigniter?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, locking

I have to run this sql routine in a model:

```
$this->db->query('LOCK TABLE orders WRITE');
$this->db->query('TRUNCATE TABLE orders');
$this->db->query('INSERT INTO orders SELECT * FROM orders_tmp');
$this->db->query('UNLOCK TABLES');
```

but I get this error:

> Error Number: 1192
>       Impossible to execute the requested command: tables under lock or transaction running
>       TRUNCATE TABLE orders

I use MyISAM as DB engine on this table.

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

To perform many INSERT and SELECT operations on a table real_table when concurrent inserts are not possible, you can insert rows into a temporary table temp_table and update the real table with the rows from the temporary table periodically. This can be done with the following code:

```
mysql> LOCK TABLES real_table WRITE, temp_table WRITE;
```

Kindly ask if it not worked for you.

Comment: This post may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951161/mysql-myisam-table-locking

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't works! The first sql I do is: "LOCK TABLES orders WRITE, orders_tmp WRITE" but I get an errors from CI that says that table orders is not locked...:(

Comment: It is always better to use InnoDB engine while using table or row level locking. Anyways, I'll try to give you more specific answer soon. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$this->db->query('TRUNCATE TABLE orders');
$this->db->query('LOCK TABLE orders WRITE');
$this->db->query('INSERT INTO orders SELECT * FROM orders_tmp');
$this->db->query('UNLOCK TABLES');
```

Answer (score 1):

You're required to acquire a lock for *all* tables in your query, not just the table you're writing to.  So in your case you also need a read lock on `orders_tmp`.

From the docs:

> A session that requires locks must acquire all the locks that it needs in a single LOCK TABLES statement. While the locks thus obtained are held, **the session can access only the locked tables**.

Docs here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/lock-tables.html

Cheers

Comment: This answer is in the low quality posts because it is too small.  Please expand it with description/reason.  Otherwise, others might vote to delete it.